# VC++ Mutex Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

So I'm just learning about c++ mutexes and I'm following, for the most part, the examples on MSDN. Why am I getting timeouts? I have the mutex timeout set at 2000ms and the "fake" process set at 250ms using Sleep(). You can see it processes some fine, then starts blowing up.... I know if I up the mutex timeout to something like 60000ms, it'll be fine, but why would I want it that high for only a 250ms process? Also, why is it jumping from threadid #1 to threadid #25??

Thanks!
Eric

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx

```
int createMutex(char* mutexName)
{

#define THREADCOUNT 25

    HANDLE aThread[THREADCOUNT];
    DWORD ThreadID;
    int i;

    int ID[THREADCOUNT];

    // Create a mutex with no initial owner

    ghMutex = CreateMutex(
        NULL,              // default security attributes
        FALSE,             // initially not owned
        (LPCWSTR)mutexName);             // unnamed mutex

    if (ghMutex == NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Create worker threads
    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
    {
        ID[i] = i +1;
        aThread[i] = CreateThread( 
            NULL,       // default security attributes
            0,          // default stack size
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) WriteToDatabase, 
            &ID[i],       // no thread function arguments
            0,          // default creation flags
            &ThreadID); // receive thread identifier

        if( aThread[i] == NULL )
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Wait for all threads to terminate
    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, aThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    // Close thread and mutex handles
    for( i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ ) CloseHandle(aThread[i]);

    CloseHandle(ghMutex);

    return 0;

}

DWORD WINAPI WriteToDatabase(int *ID){

    int threadID = *ID;

    char buffer[256];
    int MUTEX_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    int FAKE_PROCESS_TIME_DELAY = 250;

    DWORD dwWaitResult; 

    // Request ownership of mutex.
    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
        ghMutex,    // handle to mutex
        MUTEX_TIMEOUT);     // time-out interval

    sprintf(buffer, "NEW THREAD STARTED: #%d\n", threadID);
    printf(buffer);

    if(dwWaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0){

        // The thread got ownership of the mutex
        sprintf(buffer, "DB WRITE STATED: #%d\n", threadID);
        printf(buffer);

        Sleep(FAKE_PROCESS_TIME_DELAY); //simulate a long running process (db process?) which creates a WAIT_TIMEOUT

        sprintf(buffer, "DB WRITE COMPLETED: #%d\n", threadID);
        printf(buffer);

        dwCount++;
        ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);

        return TRUE; 
    }else{
        switch(dwWaitResult){
                case WAIT_ABANDONED:
                    sprintf(buffer, "MUTEX ERROR [%s] #%d\n", "WAIT_ABANDONED", threadID);
                    break;
                case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    sprintf(buffer, "MUTEX ERROR [%s] #%d\n", "WAIT_TIMEOUT", threadID);
                    break;
                default:
                    sprintf(buffer, "MUTEX ERROR [%s] #%d\n", "UNKNOWN", threadID);
        }

        printf(buffer);
        MutexERRORs++;

        //ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
        return FALSE; 
    }           

    return TRUE; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating 25 threads at practically the same time, if each takes the mutex for ~250ms then with each thread running back-to-back the total time for all threads to process is going to be 250ms * 25 = 6250ms. With this in mind, some of your threads are sure to time-out acquiring the mutex because you're only waiting 2000ms. Indeed, it looks like after 8 threads have processed, the rest time-out (which should come as no surprise since 250ms * 8 = 2000ms).

As far as thread #25 acquiring the mutex after thread #1, I don't believe there's any guaranteed ordering with regards waiting vs. acquiring the mutex. Run it a number of times and you'll likely get a different order on each run.

Comment: Iridium, I was under the impression that that timeout was for the thread currently holding the mutex. Are you saying that each thread in the mutex queue gets its own timeout counter?

Comment: @kenyu73 The timeout you specify is the maximum time that the thread *calling* the `WaitForSingleObject` function will wait to acquire the mutex. If it doesn't acquire it in that time, it'll return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`. It has no effect on the thread *holding* the mutex at that point.

Comment: This would imply that most implementations of WaitForSingleObject would want to use INFINITE if the data is not time sensitive.

Comment: @kenyu73 - It depends on the use-case. If there's a possibility that the process running within the mutex could hang indefinitely and never release it, then having an infinite timeout for other waiting threads will result in all of the threads that begin waiting for the mutex also hanging forever. This being said, it can often difficult to determine what to *do* in the case of a time-out, so of course setting it to infinite simplifies things somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace **MUTEX_TIMEOUT** with **INFINITE** or a greater number you wish.

You won't know which thread will work at a certain time, since OS manages them. Don't worry that thread_25 works earlier. If you want threads run in order of creation, you should manage them manually.

Comment: Right, I get that. I'm looking for a reason why or why not I'd want to do that. Why wouldn't what I have work? What happens if its set to infinite and I have a hung process that never ends?

Comment: Because when a thread gets mutex, sleeps for 250 ms and other threads are looking with anger to it. Because it got the mutex and sleeps while other threads are starving. When mutex got released, other thread gets it and sleeps too. This scenario will go on for all of your 25 threads. Actually your code works. Just wait for threads to finish their jobs.